# What is the spinning circle on IPhone data

Tags: iphone

Does the spinning circle when accessing data from the internet on an IPhone mean you are using data?  It seems it's always spinning non stop on Facebook.  I am concerned this indicates data usage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.  To see how much, or to prevent data access to certain apps when on mobile/cellular visit `Settings > Mobile (or Cellular)` and scroll to the list of apps at the bottom, here you can see what is enabled for mobile access, and how much data has been used since the last reset point.

You can reset the stats back to zero from the same page any time you like.  This is useful if you know for example that your Data billing cycle starts on the 17th, and you can set yourself a reminder to reset it on that date.

Note that the above is only really useful on iOS7, you don't say what version you use, if you use an older version the same rough idea applies only it's not split by individual applications, and you can't get granular detail or control.

Comment: In case it matters, it is Settings > *Cellular* on my American-configured iPhone. Also, note that iOS 7 provides far, far better statistics than iOS 6 or earlier ever did.

Comment: Just to clarify, the spinning icon doesn't *necessarily* mean you are currently sending/receiving data. It also spins when the browser (for example) is awaiting a response from a server. No?

Comment: @RobertCartaino It's sort of the same thing.  (About to get technical - ignore if you like!) If you have sent a TCP packet, then the data transmission isn't over until the last packet acknowledgement is received. Whether you are transmitting a large number of packets, or simply experiencing slow transmission of a relatively small amount, the indicator will still show - it's essentially an indicator that data transmission has started and not finished, rather than an activity monitor.  So while a 10 second spin may relate to a lot of data, is may also represent a tiny amount that is merely slow.

Comment: @stuffe Sort of, yes, but for troubleshooting purposes, an "always spinning" circle doesn't *necessarily* mean a lot of data usage. I had an app that was constantly spinning, but troubleshooting (as you described) showed that the app was just trickling data but taking a very long time to respond. Thanks.